# Constraits on provider_id / local_id

Tags: mysql, google-identity-toolkit

Keeping a user data in MySQL and making it fetchable by `local_id` requires creating index by the field of type `VARCHAR`. The documentation doesn't say a word about the max length.

The default MySQL index key length is [767 bytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html).

Does anyone have any more information about constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. For local_id that generated by Google Identity Toolkit, the length will not exceed 767 bytes.

Comment: This is the default max size index key. If one uses utf8 than the size doubles.
The local_id looks like printable string.
Is there a guarantee that the local_id be alfanumeric/ascii? I could possible cast local_id string to bytes if yes.

Comment: Yes, local_id generated by Identity Toolkit only contains printable ascii characters.